# Projection and calling a method, "The specified type member 'Member' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm starting with EF, and have this problem when I want to have a projection in a linq-to-entities query

The original entity

```
public class RealClass {
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Description {get; set;}
public decimal ValueOne {get; set;}
public decimal ValueTwo {get; set;}

// Other 100 properties..

public decimal TotalValue {
get
{
return this.ValueOne + this.ValueTwo; // It's an example, in my real object it is a little more complex and involves more properties
}
}

}
```

also, I have something like this:

```
public class LittleClass {
public int LittleId {get; set;}
public string LittleDescription {get; set;}
public decimal LittleTotalValue {get; set;}

}
```

and, in my repository, I want to do something like this:

```
public IList<LittleClass> GetAllLittleClass {
return myContext.Set<RealClass>().AsNotracking().Select(x => new LittleClass 
            {
                LittleId = x.Id,
                LittleDescription = x.Description ,
                LittleTotalValue = x.TotalValue // Here is the error!
            }).ToList(); 
}
```

And I get the following error

> The specified type member 'TotalValue' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

**Now the question is:**

Is there any way I can use the property TotalValue from RealClass, in wich I not get ALL of the RealClass properties and then make the projection? (that is no good because that entity is huge and I only need to show that 3 columns in a grid).

thanks!

PS: sorry my english!

Answer (score 1):

EF has no idea how to turn your custom property into SQL.

Instead, you can call `AsEnumerable()` in the middle of the query to force the rest of it to run on the client.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I don't want to call AsEnumerable() because with that, the query is going to bring ALL the data from the DB, and I only need that four properties to show in a little read-only grid.

Comment: @Ricardo: Then you can use two `select` clauses; one on the server and one on the client.

Comment: Could you give me some little example? I'm trying that but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

The better solution would be to move your getter and two properties to LittleClass:

```
public class LittleClass {
  public int LittleId {get; set;}
  public string LittleDescription {get; set;}
  public decimal ValueOne {get; set;}
  public decimal ValueTwo {get; set;}
  public decimal LittleTotalValue 
  {
    get
    {
       return this.ValueOne + this.ValueTwo;
    }
  }
}
```

and within your repository:

```
return myContext.Set<RealClass>().AsNotracking().Select(x => new LittleClass 
            {
                LittleId = x.Id,
                LittleDescription = x.Description ,
                ValueOne = x.ValueOne,
                ValueTwo = x.ValueTwo
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, It will be my last resort if i cannot make it work in the other way